# How to to have an array as a return type on a custom PSObject

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've got the following:

```
# Compare the 2 lists and return the ones that exist in the top and children (meaning they're redundant).
$redundantUsers = $usersAssignedToThisGroup | where { $usersAssignedToGroupsInThisGroup -contains $_ }

# Build the results to output
$results += New-Object PSObject -property @{
    group = $group.name #group assigned out of scope
    users = @($redundantUsers)
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to call my script like:

```
$users = ./MyScript -myParam "something" | Select users
```

Then I'm expecting to be able to type `$users[1]` in the console and get the first element of that array.

But instead, I'm having to do `$users[0].users[1]`.

How do I change my data and or call to do what I want?

I'm essentially just trying to let the script return the data in a useful way.

Comment: `$users = ./MyScript -myParam "something" | Select -ExpandProperty users`

Comment: Facepalm moment ... Feel free to add an answer. Thanks for that.

Comment: Just for further info, when I then pipe that to export CSV, I only get the array length, how would I go about getting the value instead?

Comment: Then you'd need to keep the non-expanded version 
`get-process | select -ExpandProperty Name | ConvertTo-Csv # lengths`
But if you do not expand it:
`get-process | select Name | ConvertTo-Csv # Names `

Comment: Otherwise, if you work from the array of string, you can recreate a PSObject, then you convert that psobject to CSV instead `$Users | % { [PSCustomObject]@{'Name'=$_}} | Convertto-CSV`

Comment: Excellent, thanks.